# Install base docker image from bash

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

My dockerfile is as below:

```
FROM bash:4.4
COPY prerequisites_ubuntu.sh   /temp/prerequisites_ubuntu.sh 
RUN  /temp/prerequisites_ubuntu.sh
```

### prerequisites_ubuntu.sh :

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

apt-get update  
apt-get install -y    coreutils  git-core ssh scons build-essential g++ libglib2.0-dev unzip uuid-dev python-dev autotools-dev gcc libjansson-dev cmake
```

When I do docker build "docker build --rm --no-cache  -t  my_image ."
It gives error as

```
/temp/prerequisites_ubuntu.sh: line 1: FROM: not found
/temp/prerequisites_ubuntu.sh: line 3: apt-get: not found
/temp/prerequisites_ubuntu.sh: line 4: apt-get: not found
```

The **prerequisites_ubuntu.sh** file will change for RaspberryPI or other platform

Comment: Add a shebang to your bash script. `FROM` is no bash command.

Comment: The image `bash:4.4` not have `FROM` command and also not have `apt`, `prerequisites_ubuntu.sh` not a valid bash file.

Comment: Sorry, can't catch your point, I deleted my answer.

Comment: I have updated my comment @atline could you please comment

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with the prerequisites_ubuntu.sh file. First of all, it is not an sh file. You are missing a shebang (which specifies which shell to use to execute the script). the FROM statement is part of the Dockerfile spec, not of shell scripts (which is why you get FROM: not found) as an error. And the bash image is based on alpine linux, which does not use `apt-get` but it uses `apk add`. Once you change the shell script to use `apk add`,  add a shebang, and remove the `FROM` statement it should work.

Comment: My task is that I should run a simple script prerequisites_ubuntu.sh or prerequisite_rpi.sh  which should install base image and dependant packages . The script to be run is chosen based on user input on the platform used . I have to use FROM bash else it will not allow me to do RUN inside dockerfile. How could I probably achieve this

Comment: Maybe it is good to specify in your question what exactly you want to achieve. Do you want to use this dockerfile to install a raspbarry py?

Comment: I want to run prerequisites code on ubuntu-Linux and Raspberry PI– arm linux platform.Base image cannot be ubuntu in both the platforms as far as I know. Please correct.
Therefore I want to run bash script at the beginning to choose the base image. Hence the question

Comment: The whole point of Docker is that you can run the same code on irrespective of the underlying OS (with some quirks), but it seems as if your goal is to install the packages on the underlying OS, which might be a bit more involved. You are currently installing the packages on the docker image when you call RUN.

Comment: So I can use the base image same and install dependant packages based on the Hardware I want to run the docker image .

Comment: But you can use Docker image to execute the code you want to run on both ubuntu and raspberry py. Or is there some hardware specific code you want to execute. It might be a good idea to include some examples of code you want to execute on both platforms.

Comment: Sure thanks for your inputs. I will try executing the docker image and update in case of any issues